# Mapbox giving errors while running

Tags: mapbox

[image]I have added Mapbox into my App using CocoaPods. When I run my App, I get 3 errors.

1: Value of type 'MMEEventsManager' has no member 'isDebugLoggingEnabled'

2: Value of type 'MMEEventsManager' has no member 'isMetricsEnabledInSimulator'

3: Value of type 'MMEEventsManager' has no member 'isMetricsEnabledForInUsePermissions'

This is my Code, just a test code:

import UIKit
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let url = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11")
    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: url)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.31, longitude: 18.06), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
    view.addSubview(mapView)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

They are internal Mapbox errors and warnings. The MMEEventsManager can log and send them (anonymised) back to Mapbox. Some more info here:
[Mapbox events](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-ios)

They're nothing for you to worry about and you could probably silence them if they became too annoying.

Comment: The problem is that my Build keeps failing because of it. I have now linked a Screenshot of the Error in the Main post

Comment: Could you add your pod file?